# .net Process: how to "monitor" process output and make the application event-responding

Tags: c#, .net

i'm trying to develop a video converter using C# and mencoder. 
At the moment it works, but i've some issues to solve. In particular

1. Is it possible to "not block" my front end application during the process is execute ? Actually my app stop to respond to event till the end of the called process
2. In Process .net class exists some event to manage the standardoutput of my application, so i can update for example a textbox with the output ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it

```
p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(MEncoderOutputHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Application.DoEvents()`
also if you call a function that blocks the code and take a long time to respond you should not call it from UI thread. just make a new thread, call the function and interact with UI.
also notice that accessing UI from another thread throw exceptions so you should handle them by using delegates or use `backgroundworker` control.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents` is *generally* a bad choice and should only be used as a workaround. The ability to get an event when output is available, or read the output stream asynchronously are both better.